# C++ adding spaces to a string of words

Tags: c++, encryption, block-cipher, letter-spacing

For example I have a cipher text code `"KWSVVSYXKSBOKRKBNRKDKXNKNBEXUKBOKDKLKBGRO"` I used some frequency analysis calculations on it and started reverse engineering to break the cipher.

My Solved cipher text is

"New solved cipherr text with key is : AMILLIONAIREAHARDHATANDADRUNKAREATABARWHENT"

The only problem now is that I dont understand how to put spaces between the words correctly so it can be a little more English `"A millionaire a hard hat and drunk are..."`

Below is my Code for breaking the cipher

```
string cipher = "";
    int i = 0, alphabet[26] = { 0 }, j, temp;
    int n = cipher.length();
    // declaring character array 
    char char_array[343];
    // copying the contents of the 
    // string to char array 
    strcpy_s(char_array, cipher.c_str());

    //print the entire cipher text and ASCII value
    //for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //{ 
        //cout << char_array[i] << endl;
    //  cout << "the ASCII value of " << char_array[i] << " is " << int(char_array[i])  << endl;
    //  }


    //Find the most frequent letter in the cipher text
    while (char_array[i] != '\0') {

        if (char_array[i] >= 'A' && char_array[i] <= 'Z') {
            j = char_array[i] - 'A';
            ++alphabet[j];
        }

        ++i;
    }
    cout << "Frequency of all alphabets in the string is:" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        cout << char(i + 'A') << " : " << alphabet[i] << endl;
    //end most frequent
    cout << endl;

    const int N = sizeof(alphabet) / sizeof(int);

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){


        cout << "Most frequent letter is : " << char(distance(alphabet, max_element(alphabet, alphabet + N)) + 'A') << " trying key : " << distance(alphabet, max_element(alphabet, alphabet + N)) << endl;
        //cout << alphabet[i] << "Most frequent position of key is trying: " << distance(alphabet, max_element(alphabet, alphabet + N)) << endl;
        cout << "New solved cipherr text with key is : " << encrypt(char_array, distance(alphabet, max_element(alphabet, alphabet + N))) << endl << endl;

        alphabet[distance(alphabet, max_element(alphabet, alphabet + N))] = 0;
    }

string encrypt(string text, int s)
{
    string result = "";

    // traverse text 
    for (int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++)
    {
        // apply transformation to each character 
        // Encrypt Uppercase letters 
        result += char(int(text[i] + s - 65) % 26 + 65);
    }

    // Return the resulting string 
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You want an algo to split text without space into words?

Comment: In the encoding you ignore anything except upper case A to Z. You can't decode information that got discarded in the encoding step.

Comment: Avoid magical numbers such as `65`, use `'A'` instead. (BTW range A-Z is not guaranty to be contiguous)

Comment: Sounds like you need to also encode spaces. You need to add a 27th character to the possible substitutions. This is hard with math on ASCII characters, but easy if you create your own array of substitution characters..

Comment: @jarod42, no. split the text using spaces

Comment: As I understand, your input before encryption doesn't have spaces (or are ignored during encryption). So you cannot use your decryption to decode space. The only solution I see is to use algorithm to add space around known words. but that is unrelated to cipher.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is to use some sort of an English dictionary and go over every character until it sees a word and then put a space there. The problem in this solution for example would be in a word like AND which can be a or an or and. So there is no way to determine where to put a space. Maybe a really sophisticated AI algorithm that determines what word should come next based on previous words that it saw.

Comment: That's what i was thinking. manually inputting common words and letting it find those in the text. The project is not big enough to implement any AI in it, but thanks anyway